# problem creating halfwave simple slot antenna radiation pattern in CST

Tags: antenna

I am trying to build a half wavelength slot antenna at 10Ghz,so lambda=300/10=30 lambda/2=15 as shown bellow.
for some reason i got two halfs of wavelength in the current distribution.
my slot length is 15mm and i am at 10Ghz.the slot is being excited by descret port.
Why i get two half wavelength?
Where did i go wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I might be a bit confused here, but where exactly do you see the see the two half wavelengths? I see a minimum in the center of the slit, which makes a lot of sense, symmetricity-wise.

Comment: Lambda=300/10=30 meter or mm?

Comment: Hello Antonio ,Its mm units

Comment: Hello marcus, i want one lobe not two. as you can see we see two maximums and one minumum in the middle.

one half wavelength is maximum in the middle and minimum in the edges.

Comment: what length do you reccomend for one lobe.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t give details on the positioning of your “discrete port” but it looks like it’s positioned at the end of the slot. To excite a half-wavelength slot you should position a voltage source at the midpoint, with one terminal on each side of the slot.

You’ve inadvertently created the equivalent of two quarter-wave slots, fed 1/2 wave out of phase, as far as radiation pattern is concerned. I’m not familiar with CST simulation, but I’d guess the feed impedance in your end-fed simulation will not be what’s expected from a typical slot.

Comment: Hello Mark,I have positioned it there for matching.
it doesnt matter the location of the feed to the length of the slot in wave length, after i moved it to the center i got the same two lobes with ruined matching.

Comment: @lub2354 Why does the slot have what looks like a step change in width in the middle? Can you make it uniform width and simulate that?

Comment: Hello Mark,it is uniform with constant width.the photo is bad

Comment: I didn't know the orientation of the slot in your radiation pattern, but now I see it's along the Y-axis. Can you enlarge the ground plane to 10 wavelengths in both directions ? I think that will eliminate that partial null perpendicular to the ground plane and give the expected pattern.